# Number of solutions of complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers, compactness

Find the number of solutions of the equation: $$|z|^5-2z|z|^3= \bar z^2 |z|^3-1$$, where $z=x+iy$,$x,y\in R, x\neq1$
My Try: Put $z=r e^{i \theta}$
$r^5-2r^4 e^{i \theta}=r^5 e^{-2i \theta}-1$
I don’t know how to solve further. The answer given is 1.

Comment: The given answer is wrong, there are 3 solutions $z = 2^{-1/4}$ and $1 \pm \sqrt{u}i$ where $u$ is the unique real root of the the quintic equation $4(u-1)^2(u+1)^3 = 1$ in $(0,1)$. If you work out the hint $|z|^2 - 2z - \bar{z}^2 \in \mathbb{R}$ in Fred's answer, you will obtain $y(1-x) = 0$. The $y = 0$ part will give you the $z = 2^{-1/4}$ solution, the $x = 1$ will give you the other two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$|z|^5-2z|z|^3= \bar z^2 |z|^3-1 \iff |z|^3(|z|^2-2z-\overline{z}^2)=1.$$

Since $z \ne 0$, we get

$$|z|^2-2z-\overline{z}^2 \in \mathbb R.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: But I get $x^4=1/2,y=0$ still two solutions

Comment: Why the downvote ?????